# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: flutter, dart

**Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.** obtaining this error message and login screen, which takes time to load and does not allow any users to log in,
i added internet permission in xml file

```
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): mWNT: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@b16a401 fN = 82 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.applyTransaction:94 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier.lambda$scheduleApply$0$SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier:71 android.view.SyncRtSurfaceTransactionApplier$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFrameDraw:4
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): mWNT: merge t to BBQ
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 9141): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 9141): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 9141): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 9141): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@405e9fd[MainActivity]( 9141): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 9141): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

login code:

```
 async{
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential= await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
      await storage.write(key: "uid", value: userCredential.user?.uid);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const StartQuiz()));
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if(e.code == 'user-not-found'){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("No User Found for that Email");
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(" No User Found for that Email",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.white),
              ),
              )
          );
    }else if(e.code == 'wrong-password'){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Wrong Password Provided by User');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(" Wrong Password Provided by User",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.white),
              ),
              )
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: after on FirebaseAuthException put catch and print that exception and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

The missed bracket is at the end of the code block, after the else if statement. Here is the code with the missing bracket highlighted:

```
    async {
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential= await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
      await storage.write(key: "uid", value: userCredential.user?.uid);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const StartQuiz()));
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if(e.code == 'user-not-found'){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("No User Found for that Email");
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(" No User Found for that Email",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.white),
              ),
              )
          );
    }else if(e.code == 'wrong-password'){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Wrong Password Provided by User');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(" Wrong Password Provided by User",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.white),
              ),
              )
          );
      }
    } // <- This is the missing bracket Add a bracket here
  }
}
```